# Managing stateful conversations per user with LangChain

Tags: chatbot, langchain, large-language-model

I'm building a chatbot using [LangChain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LangChain) that needs to have natural conversations with users to gather information from them. The chatbot needs to maintain context and state for each unique user across multiple messages and turns.

For example, if the chatbot asks for name in message 1, gets it in message 2, then asks for email in message 3, it needs to remember the previous messages and the name provided.

What is the right way to architect this type of persistent, stateful conversation per user using the LangChain library?

Should each data gathering task be a separate chain that gets invoked as needed? How can the conversation state be maintained behind the scenes across chains and messages?

Does the Context object help link conversations? Or is there another standard pattern for this use case?

I'm looking for best practices on enabling multi-turn conversations with memory without storing state in the client sending messages. The goal is to keep state isolated on the server side using LangChain constructs.

I have nothing yet. I am just investigating.

Comment: Re *"looking for best practices"*: Probably not here.

Comment: I would suggest using the memory mechanism in Langchain. The docs can be found here: https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/agent_with_memory_in_db It supports storing conversations in Redis, Postgres, any SQLAlchemy compatible database, and many others.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for best practices on enabling multi-turn conversations
> with memory without storing state in the client sending messages. The
> goal is to keep state isolated on the server side using LangChain
> constructs.

You do not want to store messages in browser because when the browser refreshes, stored data will be lost

In chat conversations, we store the chat in memory and feed the chain with the memory. You could be thinking of creating a buffer memory on the server. user asks a question, the question will be stored in memory, then the memory will be passed to the chain, the chain will make a request to open ai server and whatever response is received will be sent to the user and also saved in the chat buffer memory.

The first drawback is buffer memories are stored in computer memory. if somehow your server gets restarted by the host, all the messages will be lost. (similar to browser refresh)

The second drawback is you have to create memory for every user. If user has different chat boxes, you also have to create different memories. This will take up too much memory on the server. Excessive memory usage can lead to crashes or instability, impacting the availability of your server.

The real persistent way is to store them in a database. each user will have its own table. this table must have `conversationID`, `role` and `message`. Because you have to keep the track of who created the message. "user" or "ai".