# Langchain passing memory content to front end via response

Tags: memory, langchain, py-langchain

I've constructed a backend service in langchain, in which an agent can answer FAQs and various other functions. It interacts with a javascript frontend chatbot nicely, passing a JSON object with message and other bits and bobs

EXCEPT I can't work out how to persist memory between the two ends. I have ConversationSummaryMemory working well on the backend and it feels like I just need to include the running summary in the output, but can't quite work out how...

For info, here's the repo: https://huggingface.co/spaces/markpeace/rise-ai/tree/main/agent

Comment: what do you mean by `between the two ends.`

Comment: Oops - I mean between the frontend (javascript) and the backend (python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77749098/managing-stateful-conversations-per-user-with-langchain/77749626#77749626